# FME portuguese encoding when exporting

Tags: character-encoding, shapefile

I'm having problems with data import in FME.

My data has attributes written in Brazilian portuguese, and it contains characters like "ç", "í" among others.

I've changed the parameters to UTF-8 when I'm choosing the input (SHP file) for the workflow, but when it is exported it doesn't show the correct character, but a weird character.

My FME version is FME Microsoft SQL Server Edition 2013 SP4 (20131025 - Build 13547 - WIN32)

Please, does anyone have faced this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fellows that need help with brazilian special characters on FME, please, use WIN1252 as encoding, it works for me. Thanks!